# Video flickers on TV (mac mini, win7 + hdmi)

Tags: windows-7, mac, hdmi, tv, mac-mini

When playing video from my computer displayed on my TV the quality is not what I expected.
When the video pans from side to side to horizontal lines appear in on the TV - as if the graphics card is not powerful enough.

My setup is like this:

- Mac mini 2011 2.3GHz dual-core Intel Core i5/ 2 GB DDR3 SDRAM (PC3-10600)/500 GB HD/Intel HD 3000/Thunderbolt
- OS: windows 7
- Tv: Panasonic G10 50" plasma
- Tv and computer are connected with an 2 meter HDMI cable

I've tries to tinker with the Intel graphics driver setting, but this had no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this the first time or this is reoccurring problem? Do you have another HDMI cable to try with?

Comment: It's been going on to some months now. Changing the cable is worth a try

Comment: Bummer - changing the cable didn't help. Any other ideas?